# Are there any Specific Configuration Changes to Consider when Building an App for Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I'm accustomed to building and deploying solutions for on-premises Sharepoint instances.  I was wondering if there's any configuration changes that must be made to ensure an app can be deployed to Sharepoint Online?

Thanks much for your help and guidance.

Comment: "Configuration changes", how were you handling configuration before? You have a lot more flexibility in Apps nowadays.

Comment: Essentially, I need to know if there's anything different in developing apps targeting Sharepoint Online vs. on premise?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of SharePoint-hosted apps, you can deploy seamlessly to a local SharePoint farm or to SharePoint Online just by setting the "Site URL" property of the app project to the appropriate URL.